# Is "你什么名字? " correct?

Tags: grammar

Tatoeba contains this sentence: [你什么名字?](https://tatoeba.org/ru/sentences/show/1212007).
Usually the phrase "What is your name?" is translated as "你叫什么名字？".
Is "你什么名字?" correct?

Comment: It is correct, but rude.

Comment: "你什么名字" = "you what name?" Do you think it is ok. to say that in English?

Comment: Don't you find "What is your name?" equally impolite in English? unless of course you are a police officer interrogating a suspect.

Comment: To be fair, any translation software would translate it literally that way. There are many polite ways to ask someone's name in a normal social setting, and "你什么名字" is not one of them.

Comment: I don't think we can appraise Chinese sentences via English.  (E.g. 你叫什么名字？ = "you called what name?" is also incorrect in English.)

Answer (score 1):

1. **What is idiomatic in English does not mean its literal counterpart is idiomatic in Chinese.** For instance, we don't say `你多老` for 'How old are you?' – that would be surely a mistranslation.
2. **Grammaticality and idiomaticity are separate things.** I must disagree with r13's claim that `你什麼名字` is ungrammatical because it lacks a verb. It is at most unidiomatic (except in very limited circumstances, e.g. police interrogation as suggested by Wayne Cheah). Many Chinese sentences are of the topic-comment construction which permits the absence of a verb:

   > 這個人個子很高。 lit. Regarding this person (topic), his stature is tall (comment).

   Also, just because you can insert a verb into the verbless sentence does not prove the verbless sentence is ungrammatical.
3. **Honorifics are idiomatic in Chinese when it comes to salutatory or courteous exchanges.** It is especially not a good idea to translate expressions into Chinese literally in these instances. For example, we use `您` (honorific 2nd person singular pronoun) and `貴姓` ('surname', honorific) when we ask for someone's surname (depending on the context, it can be rude if we ask for someone's full name):

   > a. 請問你姓什麼？
   > b. 請問您姓什麼？
   > c. 請問您貴姓？

   Of course, when you are meeting someone for the first time, when that person shares a similar social status to you, and when you want to be especially courteous, you may ask for their full name like so:

   > 請問該怎麼稱呼您？ lit. How may I address you?

   These examples are not exhaustive. But they are much more idiomatic expressions than `你什麼名字`.

Comment: I agree this explanation is better, but I still don't think "你什么名字?" is correct except in police interrogation as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**你什么名字？** is grammatically correct, however does feel somewhat rude, as if less words were included because you cared too little to include them.

I can understand you feel it might be grammatically incorrect, but if we look at phrases like `你什么时候去ta的家?`, it's basically using the same construction (no word between the 你 and the question word `什么时候`). The only reason this one feels more grammatically correct than the other is because we have gotten used to hearing this construction frequently.